# Panda: Add a column to the end of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two CSV files. I am trying to extract the last column on one CSV file and paste it into the last column to the other CSV file.

The code for reading the first csv file and extracting the last column is:

```
training_label_sort = pd.read_csv('small_labels.csv', header = None).sort(input_file.columns[0])

#extract the labels from labels csv file
labels = training_label_sort.iloc[:,-1]
```

Once I have extracted the last column, I read the second csv using

```
input_file_labels = pd.read_csv('input_file_svd.csv', header = None)
```

I want to add labels(extracted from the first csv file) to the last column of the second csv file.

I tried doing:

```
input_file_labels.merge(labels.to_frame())
```

and I also tried:

```
input_file_labels.join(labels)
```

But I got errors for both the approaches. Is there something wrong in the way I am trying to join these two files?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to concat the labels column to the end of the second df?
if so you can just do:

```
input_file_labels['labels'] = labels
```

Comment: But `input_file_labels['labels'] = labels.` worked but the only problem is that it now gives me a header column which I dont need.

Comment: Yes, you can just assign labels to the new column as labels is a Series instead of dataframe. What do you mean by "it gves me a header column". Can you give a bit example to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two csv files:

test_1.csv:

```
status,date,user,labels
Registered,12-10-2016,user1,APPLE
Registered,22-05-2016,user2,FB
Registered,19-11-2016,user3,GOOGLE
```

test_2.csv:

```
status,date,user
Registered,12-10-2016,user1
Registered,22-05-2016,user2
Registered,19-11-2016,user3
```

You could copy the last column from `test_1.csv` and merge all data from `test_2.csv`, to a new file `new_test_2.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
csvfile1 = 'test_1.csv'
csvfile2 = 'test_2.csv'
training_label_sort = pd.read_csv(csvfile1)
data = list(training_label_sort['labels']) # get last column of csvfile1
with open(csvfile2, 'r') as fin, open('new_'+csvfile2, 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, lineterminator='\n')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['labels'])
    for row, val in zip(reader, data):
        writer.writerow(row + [val])
```

new_test_2.csv:

```
status,date,user,labels
Registered,12-10-2016,user1,APPLE
Registered,22-05-2016,user2,FB
Registered,19-11-2016,user3,GOOGLE
```